# Can't connect to Apache Server Remotely

Tags: linux, apache

I set apache in puppy linux and can see files in localhost.However,when I opened port80 and tried to connect apache from iphone but it failed. I could see just a white page.Maybe it wassn't 404 because it didn't show 404 error.(before I opened the port, i saw 404.)

I have configured apache.conf to Allow from all.

The access log and error logs showed nothing.

this is iptables-L

```
Chain INPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW tcp dpt:ftp 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW tcp dpt:ssh 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW tcp dpt:smtp 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW tcp dpt:domain 
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW udp dpt:domain 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW tcp dpt:finger 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW tcp dpt:www 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW tcp dpt:pop3 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW tcp dpt:auth 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW tcp dpt:imap2 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW tcp dpt:443 
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW udp dpt:syslog 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW tcp dpt:printer 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW tcp dpt:993 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW tcp dpt:995 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW tcp dpt:www 
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW udp dpt:www 
A   CCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW 
 TRUSTED    all  --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW 

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DROP       icmp --  anywhere             anywhere            state INVALID 

Chain TRUSTED (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere            icmp echo-request 
DROP       icmp --  anywhere             anywhere            
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            reject-with icmp-port-            unreachable
```

Netstat

```
tcp        0      0 192.168.100.100:80      0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
```

How do i solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

> tcp        0      0 192.168.100.100:80

The problem is right here. The server is listening at a specific, local, IP address, rather than 0.0.0.0.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.When i opened port 80 in my rooter,I used that ip, so I thought i had to use it.So, what ip should i use? could you tell me?

Comment: I've written "Listen 0.0.0.0.:80" in my ports.conf, but it didn't  work.404 error.netstat shows"tcp 0  0 0.0.0.0:80 0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      9608/apache2 " sorry for bothering again.How should i solve this?

Comment: That's exactly what it should show. Error 404 proves that the connection worked. The server sent you that code over the connection. It means that the URL you requested wasn't found there. This is progress.

Comment: Thanks.now, I can connect to apache from another machine.